# Why printed HTML content in fixed page size is sometimes wrong

Tags: html, css

I've created a newspaper layout with the HTML and CSS and I want to print this content to PDF in certain fixed page size (A3).
I use this code for all pages:

```
@page {size: A3; margin: 0;} 
@media print {html, body {width: 248mm;height:297.2mm;}}
```

The result is mostly like this: [image: page1]

But in very few times the result change Like this: [image: page2]

1.My First question is why this is happening?

2.Why div not filled the entire page even though it has fixed width and height like the print page?

This is my innerHtml:

```
<body>
   <div id="board" style="direction: rtl;">
         <div id="pageContiner" style="width: 248mm; height: 297.2mm; position: relative;"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: when writing your print media query you can remove the fixed width and change it to whatever you want example @media print {.container{position: relative; width: 100%}}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found what cause the problem; Hidden Overflow!

And I just add `Overflow: hidden` to parent div and the problem solved!